# Заявка по или на?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно написать?

> Просим положительно рассмотреть нашу заявку на предоставление торговой  площади.

или

> Просим положительно рассмотреть нашу заявку по  предоставлению торговой площади.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: **заявку на предоставление торговой площади.**

ЗАЯВКА, ж. 1. Заявление о своих правах или **о предоставлении** прав на что-л. Сделать заявку. Представить заявку. **З. на изобретение.** 2. Заявление с указанием на потребность в чём-л., требование на получение чего-л. Учесть заявку. З. на билеты, на топливо, на строительные материалы.